# Whether load gets distributed when reading from two ports rather than single port from 50k concurrent connections

Tags: node.js, load, out-of-memory, tcp, tcpserver

I am having a simple server program which just reads and sends reply back to the client. Am connecting 1000 clients pumping 4096 bytes of data concurrently and continuously. But my server is getting crashed showing out of memory error. My analysis is that messages are getting accumulated in the buffer.
     My doubt is when i have two different ports in the same server receiving from 500 clients each may decrease accumulation of message in the buffer?
     Please help me on this.

### My node js code for server

```
    var net = require('net');
    var readline=require('readline');
    var HOST = '10.44.75.21';
    var PORT = 6969;
    net.createServer(function(sock) {
        var i = readline.createInterface(sock, sock);
        console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

      // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
      i.on('line', function(data) {

     //console.log('Application Name : ' + data);
     // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
     sock.write('Connected to "' + data + '\n"');

     });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

    }).listen(PORT, HOST);

    console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's highly unlikely to make a difference.

JavaScript is single-threaded. Whether you have 1 listen port, or N listen port is irrelevant. Requests will be handled one after the other, and the incoming port shouldn't make any impact on memory usage.

A better solution is to put a load-balancing reverse proxy in front of multiple instances of the same server logic, where each instance is listening to a different port.

With enough load, this will fail as well, but it will buy you some time.
Combined with an [auto-recovery scheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) this will guarantee your server is always ready to handle requests.

Comment: but whether there is any possibility that messages will not accumulated?

Comment: else if I am using java multi threaded programming.  When two ports will be able to reduce load?

Comment: Actually I need to rethink my answer because I didn't quite understand your question before. Are you testing by having 1000 clients connecting, then once connected they each pump messages ***without*** ever disconnecting? If so, the section about separate buffers is wrong and irrelevant.

Comment: yes am connecting 1000 clients and pumping messages continuously. Whether buffer space is common for all the ports or separate space will be allocated for each port?

Comment: @madz - modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Amit Whether there is any option to reject messages from a port after certain number of messages received(i.e. after threshold limit